# How do I discover all mailboxes for an Exchange Server using Exchange Web Services?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007, ews-managed-api

I'm using Exchange Web Services Managed API 1.0 to access the Exchange servers (2007) in my organization.  I need to iterate over all the mailboxes on a given server.  I haven't seen a way to get the list of mailboxes defined for a given Exchange server.  I have been able to use the AutoDiscover service to find the address of a hub server for a specific mailbox, but I'm interested in getting a list of all mailboxes.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is not yet solved I would you recommend use just pure LDAP queries instead of Exchange Web Services. The information which you need are saved in `homeMDB`, `msExchHomeServerName` and probably `homeMTA` Active Directory attributes. You can modify LDAP query from http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Creating_a_list_of_Users_and_their_email_addresses_in_Exchange_2000_2.html or http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125087(EXCHG.65).aspx to receive information which you need.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I ended up using a powershell cmdlet to get this info, but your solution seems more elegant.

Comment: @HowardPinsley - could you post the powershell code you used?  I have a similar problem and can only use EWS